# Perl inline subroutines and conditional operator for sort

Tags: perl

So I have the following code which works:

```
my $cmp;                                                                    
if ( $action eq DEL ) {                                                     
    $cmp = \&cmpb;                                                          
}                                                                           
else {                                                                      
    $cmp = \&cmpf;                                                          
}                                                                           

foreach my $x ( sort $cmp keys %y ) {
    # do something
}
```

And cmpb and cmpf here are:

```
sub cmpf { $a cmp $b }                                                          
sub cmpb { $b cmp $a }
```

Now my question is I'd rather have something like:

```
foreach my $x ( sort $action eq DEL ? \&cmpb : \&cmpf keys %y ) {
    # do something
}
```

Or even better:

```
foreach my $x ( sort $action eq DEL ? { $a cmp $b } :  { $b cmp $a } keys %y ) {
    # do something
}
```

So two questions. First, what is the correct way to have those functions inline, and second, why don't the above work?

Comment: Try `foreach my $x ( sort {$action eq "DEL"? $a cmp $b : $b cmp $a ;} keys %y ) {# do something}`

Comment: thanks that works (dropping the quotes as DEL is a constant). Why wouldn't the ternary operator work as I try to pass one or the other function to the sort function? In any case feel free to add that as a solution and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidMokonBond because parsing. There are a few places where you might expect to be able to usefully give an arbitrarily complex expression returning a scalar, but which actually only accept a plain scalar variable. This is one of them; the filehandle argument to `print` and friends is another. (There are more too.)

Comment: if you are sorting a very large hash, this will be faster: `foreach my $x ( $action eq DEL ? sort { $b cmp $a } keys %y : sort { $a cmp $b } keys %y )` since basic types of sorting (ascending, descending, numeric ascending, numeric descending) are optimized to not actually call into the perl code for comparisons.

Comment: @ysth the peephole optimizer actually recognizes those? News to me, but pleasant news. I thought `sort @things` was way faster than `sort { $a cmp $b } @things`.

Comment: IIRC only exactly `{$a cmp $b}`, `{$b cmp $a}`, `{$a <=> $b}`, `{$b <=> $a}` (syntactically; whitespace can vary) are optimized; `use Benchmark "cmpthese";@a=1..1e6;cmpthese(-5,{default=>sub{()=sort@a},explicit=>sub{()=sort{$a cmp $b}@a},nonopt=>sub{()=sort{return $a cmp $b}@a}})`

Comment: `my $cmp = $action eq "DEL" ? sub{ $b cmp $a } : sub{ $a cmp $b }` or hash of anon subs would be my choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider also

```
foreach my $x ($action eq DEL ? reverse sort keys %y : sort keys %y) {
```

which is pretty compact and pretty readable. Perl optimizes `reverse sort` by inverting all of the comparisons; it doesn't sort the list one way and then reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the ternary operator inside the `sort` function.

```
foreach my $x ( sort {$action eq DEL ? $a cmp $b : $b cmp $a ;} keys %y ) {
    # do something
}
```

Here's a link to the docs on [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html). You can put any function you want within the `{ }`.

---

@ysth pointed out this would be faster

> since basic types of sorting (ascending, descending, numeric
>   ascending, numeric descending) are optimized to not actually call into
>   the perl code for comparisons.
>   - ysth's comment

```
foreach my $x ( $action eq DEL ? sort { $b cmp $a } keys %y : sort { $a cmp $b } keys %y )
```